# How to use prettyPhoto plugin with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, prettyphoto

I am trying to use prettyPhoto iframe plugin in my angularjs project.
I use this plugin successfully, it runs correctly in a local server but when I run that code on grunt serve:dist or when I upload my project on heroku server (I use heroku server and firebase as nosql) it shows a white page.

Comment: Is there any solution or not...?